# Open XML document ContentControls problem with signed id's

Tags: ms-word, interop, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have an application that generates Open XML documents with Content Controls.

To create a new Content Control I use Interop and the method `ContentControls.Add`. This method returns an instance of the added Content Control.

I have some logic that saves the id of the Content Control to reference it later, but in some computers I've been having a weird problem.

When I access the ID property of the Content Control I just created, it returns a string with the numeric id, the problem is that when this value is too big, after I save the document, if I look through the *document.xml* in the generated document, the `<w:id/>` element of the `<w:sdtPr/>` element has a negative value, that is the signed equivalent of the value I got from the `Id` property of the generated control.

For example:

```
var contentControl = ContentControls.Add(...);
var contentControlId = contentControl.ID;
// the value of contentControlId is "3440157266"
```

If I save the document and open it in the Package Explorer, the `Id` of the Content Control is "-854810030" instead of "3440157266".

What have I figured out is this:

```
((int)uint.Parse("3440157266")).ToString()  returns "-854810030"
```

Any idea of why this happens? This issue is hard to replicate because I don't control the `Id` of the generated controls, the `Id` is automatically generated by the Interop libraries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've had the very same type of issue in the past. The ID is unreliable as it doesn't seem to perpeturate. What I did instead is stored a name of the Content Control's `.Tag` so I could access it later.

Answer (score 1):

When displayed in 32-bit binary format, -854810030 and 3440157266 are just the same!

Answer (score 0):

This *problem* is mentioned in the [MSDN documentation of the ContentControl.ID Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192748.aspx):

> When you get the ID property value at runtime, it is returned as an unsigned value. However, when saved into the Office Open XML file format, it is saved as a signed value. If your solution attempts to map programmatically returned values to values saved in the file format, you must check for both the unsigned and signed version of the value obtained from this property.

As Claude Martel mentioned, -854810030 and 3440157266 are ident. You can easily check this by casting the signed `Int32` to a unsigned `UInt32`:

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32("-854810030 ");
UInt32 uId = (uint) id;

Assert.AreEqual(3440157266, uId);
```